# Get a length of a php's result

Tags: php, sql

I don't know php at all so sorry for a simple question - I've got the project started by another person so now I'm trying to finish it.

The problem is - I'm making an android app for which I can't make a change without changing a php and this language I don't know.

here's this part :

```
function getPlaces(){
    $result = array();
    $sql = "SELECT id, name, short_description, photo_list, selected, recommended, isTOP FROM place 
            WHERE id IN(SELECT id_place FROM rubric_place WHERE id_rubric IN(SELECT id FROM rubric WHERE name = '".$_REQUEST["rubric"]."'))  ORDER BY isTOP DESC";
    getConnect();
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$query){
        error100();
    }else {
        $result['code'] = 200;
        for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($query); $i++) { 
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            $result["places"][$i] = $row;
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM rubric WHERE id IN(SELECT id_rubric FROM rubric_place WHERE id_place = ".$row[id].")";
            $queryModule = mysql_query($sql);
            if($queryModule){
                for ($k = 0; $k < mysql_num_rows($queryModule); $k++) {
                    $rowModule = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryModule);
                    $result["places"][$i]["rubrics"][$k] = $rowModule;
                }
            }
            $sql = "SELECT SUM(rating)/COUNT(rating) AS rating FROM comment WHERE id_place = ".$row[id];
            $queryModule = mysql_query($sql);
            if($queryModule){
                $rowModule = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryModule);
                $result["places"][$i]["rating"] = $rowModule[rating];
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        exit();
    }
}
```

what I need is to make another function that returns in $result a value of "length" of places. I know I can find out length on the other end - in Android's app result, but this particular function will be changed so it will return by 20 results only so I need another function that returns length so plz help

Comment: what I need is to make another function that returns in $result a value of "length" of places.

Comment: this was a quote from my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count the number of characters in a json you can do:

```
$string = json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
$length = strlen($string);
```

You have to first put the json into a variable to count it, before outputting it.

To count the items in an array before you turn it into a json, you can do:

```
$length = count($array);
```

Comment: Are u sure this is a separate function that returns a length of an array?

Comment: To count the # of items in a array you just use `$length = count($array);`

Comment: Ronburgundy thanks for the only answer to my question. Make it as an answer, I'll accept it